# How to measure a driver's memory consumption in Windows?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, memory-usage, memory-leak, nic

I've heard an unchecked gossip that Realtek drivers on Windows 2008 suffer from memory leakage. My computer with this network card and OS suffers exactly from this symptom - high memory consumption.

So, is there any way to measure how much memory each driver consume?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started to write an answer to your question, and in looking up the syntax for the exact tools I've used in the past to do this, I came across this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395569/measuring-memory-use-of-device-drivers-in-windows

The second answer seems to be most closely associated with the two tools I had in mind, namely poolmon and WinDbg. The explanation is a lot better than the one I would have had though ;)

Comment: did you ever create a tool like this?